# Star Rating CSS Hover Issue

Tags: html, css

I am trying to resolve a CSS issue for my star rating using radio buttons. I want the previous siblings to be filled when hovering over the stars and also to be filled when a star is clicked upon. At the moment they only singularly fill upon hover or selection.
The HTML is auto generated by the ACF WordPress plugin so I cannot alter it.
My code and working codepen is below.

https://codepen.io/huwrowlands/pen/ExvBvgM

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
ul li {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
#listing-rating .acf-radio-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
#listing-rating .acf-radio-list input { display: none; }
#listing-rating .acf-radio-list label {
  visibility: hidden;
}
#listing-rating .acf-radio-list label { 
  position: relative;
  width: 1.1em;
  color: #FFD700;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#listing-rating .acf-radio-list label:before {
  content: "\2606";
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
#listing-rating .acf-radio-list label:hover:before {
  content: "\2605";
  font-size: 25px;
}       
#listing-rating .acf-radio-list label.selected:before {
  content: "\2605";
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="listing-rating">

  <p>CSS Star Rating<br />Automatically generated HTML markup from ACF WordPress plugin. I have added a class of selected to the third star/radio button here as this is added when a radio button is selected.</p>
  <ul class="acf-radio-list" data-allow_null="1" data-other_choice="0">
      
      <li><label><input type="radio" id="acf-field_619167fd11607-5" name="acf[field_619167fd11607]" value="5">5</label></li>
      <li><label><input type="radio" id="acf-field_619167fd11607-4" name="acf[field_619167fd11607]" value="4">4</label></li>
      <li><label class="selected"><input type="radio" id="acf-field_619167fd11607-3" name="acf[field_619167fd11607]" value="3">3</label></li>
      <li><label><input type="radio" id="acf-field_619167fd11607-2" name="acf[field_619167fd11607]" value="2">2</label></li>
      <li><label><input type="radio" id="acf-field_619167fd11607-1" name="acf[field_619167fd11607]" value="1">1</label></li>
        
  </ul>

</div><!-- #listing-rating -->
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: This tutorial should help: https://css-tricks.com/star-ratings/

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```css
 .star-rating {
              border:solid 1px #ccc;
              display:flex;
              flex-direction: row-reverse;
              font-size:1.5em;
              justify-content:space-around;
              padding:0 .2em;
              text-align:center;
              width:5em;
            }

            .star-rating input {
              display:none;
            }

            .star-rating label {
              color:#ccc;
              cursor:pointer;
            }

            .star-rating :checked ~ label {
              color:#f90;
            }

            .star-rating label:hover,
            .star-rating label:hover ~ label 
            {
              color:#fc0;
            }
```

```html
 <div class="star-rating">
  <input type="radio" id="5-stars" name="rating" value="5" />
  <label for="5-stars" class="star">&#9733;</label>
  <input type="radio" id="4-stars" name="rating" value="4" />
  <label for="4-stars" class="star">&#9733;</label>
  <input type="radio" id="3-stars" name="rating" value="3" />
  <label for="3-stars" class="star">&#9733;</label>
  <input type="radio" id="2-stars" name="rating" value="2" />
  <label for="2-stars" class="star">&#9733;</label>
  <input type="radio" id="1-star" name="rating" value="1" />
  <label for="1-star" class="star">&#9733;</label>
</div>
```

Comment: I cannot alter the HTML code. My input's are wrapped in the label's.

Comment: @HuwRowlands then you can not do this using CSS alone, you will have to use JavaScript.

Comment: but Issue in css hover Star Rating